# Change caption of lstlisting from file

Tags: listings

I load some code to my document like this: `\lstinputlisting{MergeSort.txt}`. This works perfectly, however I would like to add a caption in footnotesize to the bottom of the source code (without any tag like 'Listing 1:'). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `title` key-value option for [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MergeSort.txt}
This is a merge sort algorithm
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[captionpos=b,title={\footnotesize Merge Sort}]{MergeSort.txt}

\end{document}
```

`title` positioning is adjusted using `captionpos`.